# Setting init setters on interfaces without a concrete object at hand

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm writing a library that provides concrete implementations for interfaces at runtime using `System.Reflection.Emit`. The user should be able to write partially implemented interfaces without having the concrete types at hand.

I got most of it working, but there is a pain point with init setters which appears that it could *almost* be really neat. Because, interestingly, interface can have those:

```cs
public interface IFoo
{
    String Name { get; init; }
}
```

Obviously this object can't be created directly:

```cs
var myFoo = new IFoo { Name = "Peter" }; // doesn't compile
```

They can, however be set within generics:

```cs
void SomeFunction(String name)
{
    IFoo CreateFoo<CFoo>()
        where CFoo : IFoo, new()
    {
        return new CFoo { Name = name };
    }

    // but what to do with CreateFoo now?
}
```

My question is now how this `CreateFoo` can be passed out of the function. As it stands, it's just a method group. Ideally, I want to create a delegate from it:

```cs
Delegate delegateOfMysteriousType = MakeSomeDelegate(CreateFoo);
```

Or some other kind of object implementing

```cs
interface Creator<I>
{
    I Create<C>() where C : I, new();
}
```

But it seems that `CreateMethod` can't leave the method unless some concrete type is know to implement `IFoo`:

```cs
Delegate d = CreateFoo; // Cannot convert method group 'CreateFoo' to non-delegate type 'Delegate'
Object o = CreateFoo; // same
TakeTheDamnThing(CreateFoo); // Nothing will take this unless they already know a concrete IFoo
```

So it seems that it's impossible to transfer the information of `CreateFoo` out of the method unless one has, accessible from within the method, a concrete type implementing `IFoo`, which simply wont't exist at compile time.

If C# had classes nestable in function bodies with closure support, then the following would work:

```cs
public interface ICreator<I>
{
    I Create<C>()
        where C : I, new();
}

public void SomeFunction(String name)
{
    public class FooCreator : ICreator<IFoo> // Error: attempt to write Java
    {
        public IFoo Create<C>()
            where C : IFoo, new()
        {
            return new C { Name = name };
        }
    }

    TakeTheDamnThing(new FooCreator()); // yay!
}

public void TakeTheDamnThing(ICreator<IFoo> creator); // No concrete type to be seen!
```

But since that's not a thing in C#, that won't work either.

So, my expectation is that this is indeed impossible, but I thought it worth putting it out to the community.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't instantiate open generic type, I assume this would be required for `Delegate d = CreateFoo;` to work. The only way  I see is to use reflection i.e. get `MethodInfo` of your method and call `MakeGenericMethod` on it when type information will become available.

Comment: @GuruStron But that would have to be done from within `SomeFunction`, right? Even then I don't see how to get at the MethodInfo or the associated closure type.

Comment: By the way is there any particular reason why do you want to use `Reflection.Emit` instead of source generators?

Comment: It wasn't on my radar until now, very interesting. I may still have to use CIL weaving because I don't think you can call interface method implementations non-virtually from C#, but that's just a detail. I will have a look at that, thanks.

Comment: You can make a delegate that creates a `Foo` and initializes it, no problem. An `init` setter is nothing special on the IL level, it's just a setter with an extra `modreq`. You'll just have to use reflection as you can't write it in plain C#. If the intent is that the user should be able to do this for *any* `IFoo` (i.e. we can't know in advance that it needs a `string name` to initialize), pass an anonymous object instead and use its properties to do the initialization (`MyObjectCreationWizard<IFoo>(new { Name = "X" })`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Any `IFoo` needs a `String Name` to initialize, that's in the interface definition. The anonymous type usage you suggested works, but breaks type safety and degrades intellisense.

Comment: It's about the best you can get, since C# lacks support for higher-order generics (open generic types are allowed, open generic delegates are not). I agree with GS that a source generator can likely solve your problems in more straightforward way, since the concrete type would be available at compile time, so the IntelliSense should not be a problem there. (I don't know why you'd want to "call interface methods non-virtually", this sounds like a premature optimization concern -- one that could be taken away by .NET 7's more advanced options for devirtualization through tiered PGO.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's not an optimization: I want to support *wrapping* the interface method implementations - so when when a user eventually calls the method through the interface, the wrapper is called first which in turn must then call the original interface implementation (then non-virtually, otherwise it would be an infinite recursion). Basically, I need a way to do `base.Foo()`, but for interface methods. That can be done from CIL.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There are, however, other reasons I prefer not to use code generation. In particular, I want to be able to choose the kind of implementation at run time or from a different assembly.